# Bootstrap Carousel won't go to next image

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

The carousel will load but won't let me go to the next picture. I used this exact code on another website but it isn't working. Clicking the arrows or dot things won't do anything.

Here's my code:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <img src="img/Carousel0.png" alt= "Carousel10" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Bootstrap 3 Carousel Layout</h1>
                <pthis is="" an="" example="" layout="" with="" carousel="" that="" uses="" the="" bootstrap="" 3="" styles.<="" small=""><p></p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"  href="http://getbootstrap.com">Learn More</a>
            </p></pthis></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="img/Carousel1.png" alt= "Carousel11" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Bootstrap 3 Carousel Layout</h1>
                <pthis is="" an="" example="" layout="" with="" carousel="" that=""  uses="" the="" bootstrap="" 3="" styles.<="" small=""><p></p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="http://getbootstrap.com">Learn More</a>
            </p></pthis></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="img/Carousel2.png" alt= "Carousel12" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Bootstrap 3 Carousel Layout</h1>
                <pthis is="" an="" example="" layout="" with="" carousel="" that="" uses="" the="" bootstrap="" 3="" styles.<="" small=""><p></p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="http://getbootstrap.com">Learn More</a>
            </p></pthis></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a class = "carousel-control left" href = "#MyCarousel" data-slide = "prev">
      <span class = "icon-prev"></span>

  <a class = "carousel-control right" href = "#MyCarousel" data-slide = "next">
      <span class = "icon-next"></span>
  </a> 
</div>
```

Comment: check the target id of the carousel controls, it doesn't match the id of your carousel. `#MyCarousel` != `#myCarousel`

Comment: What other JS and/or CSS libraries you use on this project but not on the one that's working fine?

Comment: @PM77-1 Heres the CSS: http://pastebin.com/y3ff81V8

Comment: @koala_dev Nice catch! Unfortunately the problem still persists.

Comment: @user3803489 post your code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) please, so we can see and test your code easier. :)